# How to implement ilike on database column values which are encrypted using AES engine

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, sqlalchemy-utils

I am using SQLAlchemy, postgress db and Flask in my project.
I have used StringEncryptedType from sqlalchemy_utils to encrypt the data, Now when I search some exact value it gives me a result but when  try to search something partial using **ilike** it doesn't give give any result.

```
from sqlalchemy_utils import StringEncryptedType    
client_account_number = db.Column(StringEncryptedType(db.String(255), key, AesEngine, 'pkcs5'), nullable=False, index=True, unique=True)
```

Now I want to encrypt data for security reason and also implement partial searching.Is it possible to implement it using same encryption or by changing something.
Please guide me.